# jQuery dataTables ScrollBody's height is too short when has less data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, height, datatables

My datatable is look like this when it has less data

[image]

In this image, the datatable has 2 rows and it's scrollbody's height is too short, so it cant show the 2nd record. How can I increase it ? Here is my code :

```
$('#tblResult').dataTable({
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sScrollY": "300px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "sScrollXInner": "100%",
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bAutoWidth" : false,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "/COLLAT4/plugins/melanin-2.0.0/images/copy_cvs_xls.swf",
                "aButtons": [ "xls"]
            },
        });
```

Comment: What about not setting `"sScrollY": "300px"` ???

Comment: I found it. Just delete `"scrollCollapse": true,` and `"bScrollCollapse": true,`